# Clustering a large amount of text files with KMeans

Tags: python, memory, cluster-analysis

I have a folder of pre-extracted text files (data from images, pdfs, docs, etc). All up its about 222mb or 27,600 documents.

The folder is compiled into a dictionary:

```
data = {'file_name':'document text',...}
```

I then vectorize the dictionary

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents.values())
X = X.toarray()
```

Exporting 'X' to a text file reveals it is about 7gb in size!

I try and convert the vectorized data to a 2D array with PCA

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
two_dim = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

I start to get the following errors:

```
two_dim = pca.fit_transform(vectorized_data)
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

I am using 64bit Python, as far as I know. I ran $ py -0 and the asterisk was next to the 64bit version.

I have 32Gb of Memory, an Intel i7-8700K

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use IncrementalPCA from sklearn with a manageable batch size, or you can use an autoencoder with linear activation functions (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120080/whatre-the-differences-between-pca-and-autoencoder) as autoencoders can be also trained in batches. However the increase in size is due to the sparsity of the text data as the matrix resulted from vectorization contains mostly zeroes. And that increase makes you unable to handle PCA. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why `toarray`?

Text data is *sparse*, you want to use a sparse matrix.

You'll also want to use *spherical* k-means not standard kmeans.

PCA is also a bad idea.

Comment: I get an eeror that it cannot do this on a sparse matrix, so I found that I would need to do thta, I'll have a go at trying the different Kmeans.

Comment: I also found that it was because I didn't limit the features in my vectorization, so it was vectorizing EVERYTHING

Comment: Of course dropping rare words reduces memory, so does using single precision floats. But this kind of data is 99% 0s, and that is why you should optimize for ssparse data. And you need to get a **spherical** k-means instead anyway, because the results with "regular" k-means are worse with so many 0s.